# Preventing a table's headers from being sortable using JQuery Sortable plug-In

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css-selectors

I have an HTML table:

```
<table id="HatedByCSSOnlyGoons">
   <tr><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I'm applying the JQuery Sortable plug-In:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {

            $("#HatedByCSSOnlyGoons tbody").sortable();

            $("#HatedByCSSOnlyGoons tbody").disableSelection();

        }

    );
</script>
```

**Question:  I want every table row after the first(since this is the one with the table headers) to be sortable.  How do I limit the scope of `sortable()`?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the column headers in the `<thead>` tag and change the header cells from `<td>` to `<th>`:

```
<table id="HatedByCSSOnlyGoons">
   <thead>
       <tr><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this...I had to ask another question to get your solution to work with some webform controls in asp.net.